# Using angular-google-places-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, autocomplete, gruntjs

inculded angular-google-places-autocomplete in my project for places autocomplete using

```
bower install angular-google-places-autocomplete
```

shows an error in the console

```
Global `google` var missing. Did you forget to include the places API script?
```

following the kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete documentation included below script manually in the index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

then every works fine , but when moving to production app is build using `grunt build` then minified and uglified files are created the the same error reappears.
i think the manually added script is removed during building the app.
what to do to solve this issues.how to include this google places api in application properly.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your script for google api call before your build:js in the index.html declaration